# Assert when property has NullValueHandling.Ignore

Tags: c#, nunit, autofixture, fluent-assertions

On my endpoint's response I need to omit a property if its value is null , so I have tagged the prop with the `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` tag.

So, with the tag on the property, this property is not going to be part of the response payload and that's what I want to check/assert on my unit tests, that the property does not appear on my JSON response.

I'm using FluentAssertions as assertion framework and AutoFixture as  mock generator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I serialized the response of the endpoint, parsed it to a JObject and then validated if the token exists inside that json, something like this:

```
//Act
var result = await controller.Get(entity.Id);
var objectResult = result as OkObjectResult;
    
string serializeResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectResult.Value,Formatting.Indented);                                                           
                
JObject responseJOject = JObject.Parse(serializeResponse);
                
//Assert: this is how I checked if the tokens were or not on the json
using (new AssertionScope())
{
  responseJOject.ContainsKey("myToken1").Should().BeFalse();
  responseJOject.ContainsKey("myToken2").Should().BeFalse();
}
```

This was based on @dennis-doomen response, I took his advice, but in the opposite way, because all I wanted is to validate if the property was or not inside the response payload (json "body").

Comment: I want to add that this brings problems if your running this unit test on a pipeline, the server just crashed and throwed a OOM exception because the serialization process, so we decided to remove the unit test from the suite.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just assert the response of the HTTP request against a raw JSON? Or use something like where you deserialize the JSON into an object which structure is defined by an anonymous type. See [this example](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/EffectiveTddDemo/blob/master/Tests/DocumentManagement.Specs/12_ObjectMothers/StatisticsModuleSpecs.cs#L75) on how this works.

Comment: Please check my own response, I'll wait for your opinion or advices.

Comment: Why not do a text-based assertion on the Json?